# What is the word for a concept which represent a variety of ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which works in the following sentence:

I like John not as a person but for _____ reasons.

_______ = Due to him encapsulating disperet but interconnected set of ideas.

Comment: A [**Panoply**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/panoply) is a term that might fit your use.

Comment: I think you mean "*disparate*", not "*disperet*"...

Answer (score 1):

[myriad](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/myriad) is a word that would fit, although it might be an exaggeration:

> of an indefinitely great number; innumerable:
>   *the myriad stars of a summer night*

Answer (score 0):

[Multifarious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/multifarious) might fill the bill.

> 1. having many different parts, elements, forms, etc.
> 2. numerous and varied; greatly diverse or manifold:
>      *multifarious activities.*